# How to overcome : “Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options DENY”?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, x-frame-options

I created an application that provide (Facebook/twitter/Google+) login and every thing works fine.
But when i want to embed my application insite another website via an iframe i catch this exception :

[Error] Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXX&state=XXXX&scope=email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.XXXXX.net%2FListeningParty%2Fconnect_facebook.php%3Finit%3D1%26appId%3D5000' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. (connect_facebook.php, line 0)

I Know that facebook block it in purpose for security issues but is there a way to overcome this?
I use php-sdk of facebook

Comment: You can't overcome that. If you could overcome that, it wouldn't make sense to use that. There is a logic behind sending a X-Frame-Options header.

Comment: if I can't overcome this is there another way to have facebook login in my app and have the possibility to embed my app in other web site

Comment: I don't use facebook so I can't say anything for sure. But why don't you open a new window and then open directly the login site of your app instead of opening the login site in the frame (disqus.com does that)?

Comment: If you know it is done for security reasons. Why do you think there was a way around it. It wouldn't be very good security if you could go around it

Comment: I need to respect the specifications required by my client So i need to find a way to overcome this :(

Comment: There is no way to overcome this. The only way is if you want to let it embed in an iframe, is to open a new window to let the user login directly on your app website.